# How to perform unit testing on the methods which print to console using console.log in angualr9?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a method defined as :

```
 public log(...logMsg) {
    if (isDebug)
      consoleLog('log', logMsg);
  }
```

Is there any possible way that we can conduct unit testing on this method using jasmine and karma frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jasmine's spy function to spy on the `console`. After all, your `consoleLog` method should log something using the native `console.log()` method, so you can test it this way:

```
// spy on the native console log method 
spyOn(console, 'log').and.callThrough();

// test if the method has been called as you expect
expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo');
```

Comment: it throwing error as :Expected spy log to have been called with:
  [ 'Hello Dummy' ]
but it was never called.

Comment: Could you please share a snippet from that unit test?